# Do something when Ember component is instantiated?

Tags: ember.js

I call a component like this:

```
  {{Gd-text-input label="Specify" name="Specify" key="entry.810220554" triggerKey="tada" hideIf="Client"}}
```

I would like to run some javascript-code that sets an additional property to this component.

What I'm trying to run is something like this

```
//Convert string ot array.
GdRadioInput = Em.Component.extend({
    init: function(){
        var cs = this.get('contentString');
        console.log('doesthiswork?');
        if(cs){
            this.set('content', eval(cs));
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't run. If someone could just provide a sample that console.logs  a the value of a property of a component whenever that component is created, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run this code in the init method

```
init:function(){
    this._super();
    hideIf = this.get('hideIf');
    key = this.get('key')
        if(hideIf === key){
              this.set('class', 'hide');
        }
    }
```

Good luck

PD: now this method is private: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_init

Comment: Can I put an init in each component? like App.GdTextInputComponent = Em.Component.extend({ init:funciont(){}});

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to update it with the new way to do things.  Instead of overriding the `init` function, you can now cause a function to run on initialization with `.on('init')`.  Example:

```
GdRadioInput = Em.Component.extend({
    setupFunc: function(){
        var cs = this.get('contentString');
        console.log('doesthiswork?');
        if(cs){
            this.set('content', eval(cs));
        }
    }.on('init')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up: Just in case you are depending on a fully loaded DOM tree, you can use `.on('didInsertElement')` instead of `on('init')`:

```
GdRadioInput = Em.Component.extend({
    setupFunc: function(){
        var cs = this.get('contentString');
        console.log('doesthiswork?');
        if(cs){
            this.set('content', eval(cs));
        }
    }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

That event is fired when the view's element has been inserted into the DOM: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#event_didInsertElement